# fill list of authors and first author name in main document needed

Tags: biblatex

I want to print in the main text of my document, first a reference with all author names using \fullcite{myref} and in a later section only author et. al. \citeauthor{myref} in the references part again only author et. al style. \fullcite{} is working as expexcted, but \citeauthor{myref} also gives me full list , I want here only 1st author... Can i change settings at run-time ?

main code code

```
\usepackage[
    
    backend=biber, %use modern biber instead of old natbib
   
    
    maxcitenames=30, %when using \textcite, at max print 2 author names
    mincitenames=1, %when using \textcite and we have many authors (et al), print 1 author name then et al
    minbibnames=1, %in bibliography, when there are many authors (et al), print 1 author name then et al
    maxbibnames=4 %in bibliography, print at maximum 6 author names
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Without [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964) to test it, I guess, you are searching `\citeautor*{myref}`. See the `biblatex` manual for more information.

Comment: \citeautor*  solved my problem :-)